# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /logout from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:4444

Tags: reactjs, express, proxy

How can I solve this issue?
I tried to use axios so I can make a request to /logout but it just doesn't work and I tried it using postman and the result is the same. I also have /login and it works well

[image]

[image]

```
// LOGOUT
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
});
```

package.json in my client(maybe you need this)

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:4444",
```

this req. won't work

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/logout',
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(res => {
    localStorage.removeItem('isAuthenticated');
    return res.data;
  });
```

Comment: Can you show the login code as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.json({ message: "Successfully logged out" }); // added this and it worked for me
});
```

I just added that line of code, I found it somewhere and tried and it worked, to be honest, I don't know why it works.
The problem was probably in "req.logout()" code, if I delete it, it will work fine but with that line the error comes. I read about how to correctly logout user from passport.js and found that line of code and used it.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.